# std::move explained through an example

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how std::move works and I bumped into some problems:
so, this is the implementation:

```
template <typename T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& t){
     return static_cast<typename remove_reference::type&&>(t);
```

Let me go through this snippet line by line by using

```
string s2;
s2 = std::move(string("hello"));
```

1. the constructor for the string hello is going to return an rvalue.
2. type deduction rules tell us that if I am passing an rvalue to a parameter&& I get the referred type hence `string` in this case.
3. Now comes the static_cast part
4. `remove_reference<T>` is going to be simply `remove_reference<string>` which is simply `string`
5. What I don’t get is this type&& thing. I have seen already something like ::type but I don’t know if ::type&& makes a difference.
6. So I am converting t whose type has been deduced to string (here could be my misunderstanding) to all this thing which seems to be just `string`. I know that std::move needs to return an rvalue reference no matter if we pass an rvalue or an lvalue to it, i simply cannot get there. Could someone help?

Comment: `s2 = std::move(string(“hello”));` is the same as `s2 = string(“hello”);` ie `std::move` has no effect.

Comment: There is `std::remove_reference<std::string>`, which is a bespoke class that defines `type`.  And there is also `std::remove_reference_t<std::string>`, which is indeed an alias for `std::string`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference

Answer (score 2):

`remove_reference<string>` is NOT the same as just `string`. It is a struct that has a typedef `type` in its scope that is defined to `string`. So `remove_reference<string>::type` is `string`.

Thus `remove_reference<string>::type&&` is `string&&` which is an rvalue reference to `string`

A shorter way to write that would be `remove_reference_t<string>&&` (notice the `_t`)

Comment: thanks man very clear. So basically this ::type and ::type&& are just an aliases and in this case this is like string&&. I have seen something like that also in the implementation of a custom allocator where you need to provide the aliases in kinda the same way right?

Comment: Yes exactly, the `::type` is just an alias much like the ones provided in allocators. Only the `&&` is not part of the alias but rather an additional qualifier added to it.

Comment: Ah yeah of course, thanks again man

Answer (score 1):

1 ~ 3 are correct. From 4,

`remove_reference<string>` is ..., `remove_reference<string>`, it's not `string`. `remove_reference<string>::type` is `string`. So `remove_reference<string>::type&&` is `string&&`, i.e. an rvalue-reference to `string`. Since the return type of `std::move` is rvalue-reference, `std::move(...)` leads to an [xvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue):

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;
> - ...

As the effect, `std::move(string("hello"))` is converting an prvalue `string("hello")` to xvalue, even both prvalue and xvalue are rvalues. `std::move` is supposed to be used to convert lvalue to rvalue, so the usage like this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: thanks very much man now I got it

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly relevant to the question, but good to know.
The type of t as a template parameter looks like a rvalue-reference, but may not be

```
template <typename T>
RetType fn(T&& t)
```

It's a special case, that says : "Use T&& or constT& as required"

See [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) for a better explanation than I could ever give

Edit:
Actually, you need to know this to answer part 6 of your question.